# in-app billing doesn't work in some devices

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, device

I use the Trivial_drive code in the new android project and upload the apk file to app store and run the project in my device and emulator and it's worked fine.
but in some device like sony xperia m dual it doesn't work.
the screen shot of error:

http://www.axgig.com/images/60177538539637605313.png

and even on genymotion emulator 2.3 and 4.2 version it's work fine but in 4.4.2 version it doesn't work.

the error:

Error purchasing: Iabresult : null data in IAB Result (response:1002:bad response received)

what wrong with this?
please help me

and sorry for my bad english